# User friendly interface to network settings

Tags: networking, ssh

Right now, my team plans to deliver configured Raspberry Pi machines to our clients' homes so we can ssh to them. The only problem is that we don't have their home Wi-Fi SSID and password until we get to their house.

Unfortunately, the person doing the installation is not technical enough to use the terminal for the instructions outlined here: [Automatically connect a Raspberry Pi to a Wifi network](http://weworkweplay.com/play/automatically-connect-a-raspberry-pi-to-a-wifi-network/).

Are there user friendly Raspberry Pi user interfaces for this type of connection for people who are not technical enough to use nano or vim?

Comment: The second paragraph I'd a bit flawed. Either the person is **not** technical, or **only** that person is technical enough, but you want to enable others.

Answer (score 0):

There are already user friendly interfaces in Raspbian. (If you are deploying systems you should know this.) See [How do I set up networking/WiFi/Static IP](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697) specifically:-

> If you are using WiFi and the GUI set up by following the Foundation Guidelines https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/README.md

This, of course, assumes the network is running a secure (non-WEP) protocol.

PS The link you quoted is hopelessly out of date, and the suggested `/etc/network/interfaces` was never best practice, and I wonder it ever worked.